# Gradle build: com.android.library and spring-boot compatability

Tags: java, android, gradle, spring-boot, android-gradle-plugin

I have the following issue. I have a spring-boot-powered server which I build on my linux host. Now I need to launch it on Android device for test purposes ( due to limitations of our test framework ).

I've applied both spring-boot and android-library plugins:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
```

I get an error:

```
> The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it
  is not compatible with the Android plugins.
```

But the thing is I haven't applied **java** plugin explicitly. So why does it happen? Does spring-boot apply it silently? Or can it be some options from gradle script that apply it implicitly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, spring-boot plugin applies java-plugin by default. I didn't find it in documentation, but it could be seen in plugin's source code [here.](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/gradle/SpringBootPlugin.java)

It applies it in this line:

```
project.getPlugins().apply(JavaPlugin.class);
```

Comment: Does this mean that Spring Boot cannot run on an Android phone?